# Type constraint affects the inferred type in a declared function

Tags: typescript

When I use type constraint in type alias I see the return type as literal true. (All as expected)

```js
type InferReturn<Fn extends () => any> = Fn extends () => infer Return
  ? Return
  : never;
type R = InferReturn<() => true>; // true
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdgMwgJwEoWAV2XAPAMTiggA9gI4ATAZygAoBKKAXgD4oBDOEd5qQ4mQo16TNlACWiFFHRYcAKChQA-LIzY4SqAC4ocCADcUAbgWhIslrGloNOXIxbtgyTBFZmA9F+VQAeipAA)

When I use type constraint in declared function I see that the return type is already boolean (Not expected).

```js
declare function DeclaredInferReturn<Fn extends () => any>(fn: Fn): Fn extends () => infer Return
  ? Return
  : never;
const r = DeclaredInferReturn(() => true); // r as boolean
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwBFxo5gBJVREGAJRA2RlQB4AxfEADwxFWAGd4ACgCU8ALwA+eFFQBPSUMSoAXPHYi17eFx59BoidKyVq8OgyYAoePAD85+o1Q34a1CABu1ANxWwePwY8DAShMSwIOSmtE5MQoZS8BgwyCAifgD0mba2AHp2QA)

But, if I remove the type constraint in the declared function, I see that the returned type is again a literal true.

```js
declare function DeclaredInferReturn<Fn>(fn: Fn): Fn extends () => infer Return
  ? Return
  : never;
const r = DeclaredInferReturn(() => true); // r as true
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwBFxo5gBJVREGAJRA2RlQB4AxVAPgApFUAueOwCUA9vBAAPDCFTAAzvC5D4AXg7wslavDoMmAKHjwA-DvqNUh+ANQgAbtQDc+sHjkZ4MVYWKwQ5LVpzJi4lVXUMGGQQIWcAejijIwA9YyA)

As far as I understand, a type constraint should not affect the behavior of the `infer` operator. Can someone explain why type constraints break the logic of `infer` and why it behaves differently in a declared function compared to a type alias?

Comment: I'm sure it's just an example for the question about inference, but for lurkers: There's a predefined utility type for getting the return type of a function, you don't have to create your own as above: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype But again, I think that's tangential to the question being asked here.

Comment: ```declare function DeclaredInferReturn<Fn extends () => any>(fn: Fn): ReturnType<Fn>```
In this case, I also have boolean instead of true.

Comment: If you explicitly state that your function returns true it will imply it. `const r = DeclaredInferReturn((): true => true);`. Not a practical example of why a function whenever called will return true. It is useless to be called and if it always returns true - we do not even have to call it.

Comment: The behavior you're seeing here is defined in [ms/TS#10676](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676).  Depending on the situation, a literal type like `true` may be widened to a supertype like `boolean`.  This is based on heuristics that work well in many situations; usually if someone writes `() => "abc"` they want `string` and not `"abc"`.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz - Is this the relevant bullet point? *"In a function with no return type annotation, if the inferred return type is a literal type (but not a literal union type) and the function does not have a contextual type with a return type that includes literal types, the return type is widened to its widened literal type."* I.e., the constraint provides a contextual type for the function (`() => any`), but `any` doesn't include the literal type `true`, so it gets widened?